# Javascript console in WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I was wondering how can I read and send messages in the javascript console from `WebBrowser`s.
The Console I'm speaking of is the one that appear when you press F12 in a browser.

Let's say that I can do "API.getMedia" on the site that I want to show, is there anyway to make the information of "API.getMedia" appear on a Label?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write JavaScript to execute the command `API.getMedia` and output the results in an existing `<div>` or `<span>` or wherever you would like.

In VB.Net, a `asp:Label` control is converted into (I believe) a `<span>` so you could easily define a placeholder `asp:Label` with an id that you can then target with the JavaScript to insert the result of the `API.getMedia` call.